# How to download Google Drive Folder using wget?

Tags: google-drive-api, wget

I need to download whole folder from google drive using `wget`.
How can I do that?

Comment: You can't. You'll need to download each file individually.

Comment: good info here:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136371/how-to-download-a-folder-from-google-drive-using-terminal

Answer (score 9):

"You can't" more and less...

```
pip install gdown
gdown --no-check-certificate --folder <folder URL>
```

I've been using it for a while in macOS and Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

You can download zipped files like this:

Suppose this is the shared link from your google drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/345efwerfer23rffedser/view?usp=sharing

copy this part of the shared_link: 345efwerfer23rffedser

to bellow command

!wget --no-check-certificate 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=345efwerfer23rffedser' -O 'files.zip'